# SQL: inner join if view exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
select a_table.fname,a_table.lname,a_view.tell 
from a_table 
if exists(select 1 from sys.views where name='a_view' and type='v')
{
    inner join a_view on a_table.id=a_view.id
}
```

My questions:

inner join my table with a view if i created view before
and if a_view exist then show a_view.tell because a_view is in a_view!
its incorrect if i select a_view.tell when a_view is not exist

Comment: Can you not use an outer join and check for nullity instead of the 'if' block?

Comment: yes i can but i need to use some thing like " if " instead of outer join !

Comment: You didn't tell us your DBMS. Maybe the one you're using can something special, but in general the objects in a query must exist when the query is parsed or else there is an error. And you cannot use a conditional like you did in a plain SQL query. Likely you'll have to use dynamic SQL to accomplish what you want, i.e. first building a query as a sting and then executing it.

Comment: SQL Server 2012
thanx sticky bit
i still want some different answer !

Comment: OK. I added the tags for you. Next time please remember to do it yourself. However I don't see this happen in SQL Server without the use of dynamic SQL. But I'd be happy to be wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic sql could be used for this.

```
DECLARE @DynSql VARCHAR(max);

SET @DynSql = 'select fname, lname from a_table';

IF OBJECT_ID('a_view', 'v') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
   SET @DynSql = 'select 
  t.fname, t.lname, v.tell
from a_table t
join a_view v on v.id = t.id';
END

EXEC (@DynSql);
```

Comment: pleas see my edited question
inner join my table with a view if i created view before
and if a_view exist then show a_view.tell because a_view is in a_view!
its incorrect if i select a_view.tell when a_view is not exist

Comment: @AliMousavi See update. You could make it more complicated by using an extra variable for the column names. But just changing the whole SQL is easier in the simplified example anyway.

Comment: @AliMousavi A sidenote. If you want to add a WHERE clause. Use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) with parameters. It's to prevent possible Sql-injections.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Create the view!  Don't make your queries conditional on whether or not tables or views exist.

A database is supposed to have a structure, and there is little to no reason to not have the tables and views that you need.

So, long before you get to where this query is needed, be sure the view exists.  I'm not sure what this requires in  your environment but it might include:

- Creating the view with the right permissions so it cannot be accidentally deleted.
- Scheduling a job that checks to be sure the view exists and/or updates the view periodically.
- Creating the view earlier in the script where this should be used.